# Mysql some update queries not working made after insert query

Tags: mysql, yii, innodb

I have an app made with Yii framework. In user component I firstly create new user model (insert a row with user data) and then in a controller I update that same model with adding additional data to the model. Sometimes (about 5% of time) some update queries fail. That means when looking into to database the data added with update query is not there.

When using insert query to insert same data to different table then it is allways available.

I am using amazon aws RDS small mysql instance. The table is INNODB.

Comment: Please show us the code. Without it, all I can really say is that you, my friend, are doing something wrong.

Comment: have you tried putting the `$model->update()` call in a conditional block to check if the model has errors? That's the most likely source of update errors.

Comment: Check if validation was successful. `if(!$model->save()) print_r($model->getErrors());` Have you changed `User` class implementation recently? Maybe you should regenerate rules for this model (with Gii tool)?